# Defining foreign key for a composite primary key in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I have two tables: `Ticket` and `TicketRelation`. I am trying to relate 2 `Tickets` using the `TicketRelation` table.

I want to add a cascade constraint to both foreign keys.

[image: classes]

I am using SQL Server Management Studio to add the constraints but I get this error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_destiny_ticket' on table 'ticketRelation' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I also tried to do this with a trigger, but I am not sure how to define it.

Here I provide the tables definitions:

This is the base entity TICKET

```
CREATE TABLE ticket 
(
    ticket_id BIGINT,
    some_data VARCHAR (50),

    CONSTRAINT PK_ticket PRIMARY KEY (ticket_id)
);
```

and the relational table TICKETRELATION

```
CREATE TABLE ticketRelation 
(
    origin_ticket BIGINT,
    destiny_ticket BIGINT,
    relation_data VARCHAR (50),

    CONSTRAINT PK_ticket_relation PRIMARY KEY (origin_ticket, destiny_ticket),

    CONSTRAINT FK_origin_ticket FOREIGN KEY (origin_ticket)
        REFERENCES ticket(ticket_id),

    CONSTRAINT FK_destiny_ticket FOREIGN KEY (destiny_ticket)
        REFERENCES ticket(ticket_id),
)
```

I want to add an `ON DELETE CASCADE` constraint to both foreign keys:

```sql
    CONSTRAINT FK_origin_ticket FOREIGN KEY (origin_ticket)
         REFERENCES ticket(ticket_id)
              ON DELETE CASCADE, -- I want to add this --

    CONSTRAINT FK_destiny_ticket FOREIGN KEY (origin_ticket)
        REFERENCES ticket(ticket_id)
             ON DELETE CASCADE, -- and this --
```

Comment: Off-topic - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). Short answer is you can't do this. Search the internet on the error text to find many discussions, suggestions, and work-arounds.

Comment: You can't do this with SQL Server, but you can with some other DBMSs, if you have the freedom to switch.